# Modifying a text path after text has been placed on it

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, text, path

In a recent project in Illustrator I was creating freeform paths to place text on them.  Since the design was freeform I kept running into a problem where I would create a path, place the text on it, then realize that the text didn't fully fit on the path or the path needed to be tweaked slightly to make the text look right.  However, once I placed the text on the path I found that I couldn't modify the path's anchor points anymore.

Is it possible to modify an text path's anchor points once you have placed text on it?  Or do I have to undo the text on a path action, modify the line, and then place the text back on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Direct selection tool ([image]) you can click on the path after you've placed your text and edit the curves and nodes as much as you'd like.

[image]

Comment: I thought I had tried this and couldnt seem to get it to work...Ill have to give this a try again in a little bit :)

Comment: If you choose the direct selection tool and immediately click and drag one of the points, you'll end up moving the entire path, the key is to click once on one of the nodes. Then the curve handles will be available to you...hope that helps.

Comment: I must have been extremely tired or something when I tried this before - it works exactly as described.  Thanks @circleb

Comment: :-) no problem, I know the feeling!

Comment: Shittiest UI in world history

Answer (score 1):

One small addition to Circle B's answer - you need to first use Direct Selection on one of the points *that is not the end of the path* - only then can you modify the path ending nodes (e.g. to lengthen the path).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/110720)

Comment: Not only does it provide an answer to the question, it provides a better one than the top answer.